# iCloud data transfer to other cloud

Tags: icloud

I have no other choice but to adopt iCloud right now. In the near future i would like to build my own cloud service. Is there any problem if the app transfers all the data from iCloud to my own cloud?

- Only the data related to my app of course.
- After user's permission.

Is Apple positive about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, would Apple approve an app for the store that was going to transfer the user's iCloud data to some other online service, as usual all we can do is try and gauge the odds.

- None of Apple's guidelines even hint that apps may not use non-iCloud services.
- Neither do they hint that there's any issue with moving data from one service to another, even if one of them is iCloud.
- Apple *does not* look kindly on apps that transfer user data to online storage without the user's knowledge. Assuming you make it clear to users what you're doing, this is probably not an issue, but users should have the chance to opt out of your service.

Based on information available right now, what you suggest is **probably** OK so long as your app makes clear what's happening. It's unwise to try and predict Apple's app-approval actions too closely. They might change their policies tomorrow, or they might decide to reject your app for reasons that had not previously been stated. At the moment though, switching services like that seems likely to be accepted.